# adding property sources in configuration classes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-profiles

I have to load a properties file and the path of which is determined at runtime along with figuring out the properties file format. Which means I cant just specify the location. I have a properties loader class that reads the file and converts into key value pairs. In the past I would do this by implementing ApplicationContextInitializer but in this application I am using configuration classes and there is no web.xml file to register this listener in. How can I tap into the startup process of a @EnableWebMvc configuration class to call my properties loader class and add the map returned from it as a proeprty source.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To hook an `ApplicationContextListener` into a Servlet 3.0 environment, you can do this one of two ways:

- include a web.xml or web-fragment.xml which defines the `contextInitializerClasses` context-param whose value is the class name for the implementation. You can have both annotations and either / both of these deployment descriptors in your web app (the XML files are of higher precendence than annotated classes)
- call `setInitParameter("contextInitializerClasses", MyImplementingInitializer.class.getName())` method on the `ServletContext` class from a class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer`, annotating the class with `@Order(1)` to ensure that it runs before other `WebApplicationInitializer`s

Comment: I think i need to also implement ApplicationContextInitializer to get access to ConfigurableWebApplicationContext to add the proprerty source. How can i register this listener without web.xml

Comment: Why couldn't you just add definitions by defining a @Configuration class and specify that class when you override getRootConfigClasses()? Why specifically do you need to use an ApplicationContextInitializer?

Comment: okay so the exact thing that I am trying to do is to load a file at startup which is in pipe delimited form. I need to read the file and convert the pipe delimited data into a map and then load that map as another PopertySource. One way i have done in past is register the ApplicationContextInitializer in webxml and then since in this class i have access to context and environment I am able to load these proeprties .. again all i need to do is tap into startup process while having access to applicationContext and environmetn object to add a property source

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't realize that `ApplicationContextListener` was so closely tied into servlet context parameters, and what you are doing really is ApplicationContext (not BeanFactory) specific. I've updated my answer.

Comment: its still not clear. I am already registering the dispatcher servlet I am assuming in my class that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in the configureDefaultServletHandling overridden method by calling configurer.enable. So now what you are suggesting is that i create another class that implements WEbApplicationInitializer and create the dispatcher servlet in there .. what would happen with the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class. With all these million ways to set things up is getting really confusing. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: another part I am not sure about is right now I dont have a WebApplicationInitializer implementation and no web.xml file but my configuration classes still get picked up and everything gets registered. Then why do i need to implement the WebApplicationInitializer class and explicity register my Configuration classes as shows in javadoc for WebApplicationInitializer